# How to get BibLaTex to completely ignore prenotes?

Tags: biblatex, citing, notes

Assumed we have this **Minimum Working Example (MWE)**:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{Bibliograpy.tex}
    @article{Mueller,
        author = {Mueller, Michael},
        title = {Testing LaTeX},
        date = {2020}}
\end{filecontents}

    \addbibresource{Bibliograpy.tex}

\begin{document}

    This is a citation including page numbers \cite[5]{Mueller}.

    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image: Screenshot of the result]

---

How can I tell `BibLaTex` to ignore the `prenote` globally while keeping it alive in the `prenote`-field of the citation in LaTeX source code?

In other words: I want to hide the visibility of "p. 5" in the PDF while keeping it alive inside the source code. Therefore I would like to reconfigure BibLaTeX to hide/ignore `prenotes` globally.

Comment: The `, p. ` is added to the `5` during processing of the prenote parameter of the citation command. Do you want to keep the value 5, or the typeset form? In either case, you want the reference to show just `[1]`, not `[1, p. ]`? Or if you do, you can print white text on white background - it won't *appear*, but can be copied.

Comment: @Cicada: I want to remove this whole text block ("p. 5") from the PDF. It should be preserved in the LaTeX source code, but completely beeing ignored by `BibLaTeX` when compiling, so `BibLaTeX` should treat it like there would no `prenote` be existent.

Comment: I appreciate this question and that it may be required, but I am curious why you need to remove the postnote. What sort of publication would want you to not document the page numbers of your references?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question mentions `prenote` but the MWE shows a `postnote`, so I will show how you can get rid of the `postnote`. The approach is the same for `prenote`.

Internally `postnote` is handled like a normal field when the citations are typeset, so you can delete it with `\clearfield{postnote}`. This can be done in an `\AtEveryCitekey` hook.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{postnote}}

\begin{document}
  Lorem \autocite[5]{sigfridsson}.

  ipsum \autocite[5]{nussbaum,worman}.

  dolor \autocites[5]{geer}[56]{nussbaum}.

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem [3].//ipsum [2, 4].//dolor [1, 2].]

Comment: Don't do that! If you've already put in the work to pinpoint the reference more precisely share that with your readers as well: They will appreciate it.